# For what values of $n$ from $1$ to $2020$ do the expressions $n^2+4$ and $n+3$ share a common factor greater than $1$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

For what values of $n$ from $1$ to $2020$ do the expressions $n^2+4$ and $n+3$ share a common factor greater than $1$?

I'm not sure what to do since the $n$'s are of different powers. Any help?

Comment: Do you mean a factor greater than $1$? $0$ is never a factor of a non-zero number.

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be 1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:  Any factor common to $n^2+4$ and $n+3$ is also common to $n^2+4$ and $k(n+3)$ and to $n^2+4-k(n+3)$.  You can choose $k$  to simplify the expression.  It can contain $n$ if you like.  One more step of this and you will be down to just one possibility of common factor.

Comment: I already have that. I have an expression 4-3n that seems to be useless to me. I can't figure out how to use it. (It means that it is your hint with k=n)

Comment: Good.  Now you want common factors between $4-3n$ and $n+3$.  You can do the same thing with $4-3n-k(n+3)$.

Comment: Oh! So if k was 3, then it would be -5.

Comment: Does that suggest it is none then?

Comment: nvm I multiplied wrong k=-3

Comment: No, you want $k=-3$ to get the $n$s to cancel.  If you did get $-5$ you would know that the only common factor possible was $5$

Comment: That gives 13. What does that mean?

Comment: Oh! So do all n so that n+3=13m work?

Comment: or does only 10 work. Since both 23 and 36 don't work.

Comment: Sure $23$ works. $ 23^2+4=533=41 \cdot 13.$  $\ \ 36$ works as well.  $36^2+4=1300$

Comment: oh right, only one factor shared! XD Sorry lol Thank you so much!

Comment: I got 155. (2020/13)

Comment: That is right, but you would be wrong if the upper limit were raised to $2026$.  If you divide $2026/13$ and round down you still get $155$, but 2025$ has been added as a solution.